# (C#) Selenium How do I choose an option within a ComboBox?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[image]

How do I select the "Acknowleg " option of my ComboBox "Acknowleg Type"?

I tried the following code:

```
var test = new SelectElement(_driver.FindElement(By.Name("Activity Type")));
test.SelectByText("Acknowlege");
```

```
_driver.FindElementByCssSelector("#divFormTemplate > div.simpleWorkflowContainer > div.simpleWorkflow > table:nth-child(2) > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > select > option:nth-child(2)").Click();
```

```
var test = new SelectElement(_driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=\"divFormTemplate\"]/div[2]/div[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/select/option[2]"));
test.SelectByText("Acknowlege");
```

```
 _driver.FindElementByXPath("//select[@class='relative']/option[@value='285']").Click();
```

c# Error Code
"no such element: Unable to locate element: "

Comment: You have the website link?

Comment: Only local pc is accessible.